# order of execution in async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have been studying promises, await and async functions. While I was just in the stage of learning promises, I stumbled upon this :

```js
async function async1(){
  console.log('Async 1');
  await async2();  // *
  console.log('AFter Async 1');
}

async function async2(){
  console.log('FROM async 2');
}


async1();
console.log('Synchronous'); //**
```

Which results in:

```
Async 1
FROM async 2
Synchronous
AFter Async 1
```

How is the code jumping from * to **. How is microtask being used here ??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no microtask involved in the execution of the specific sequence you asked about (from `*` to `**`), although a microtask gets *queued* during that sequence (then run later).

An `async` function is synchronous until the first `await`, uncaught exception, or `return` (including an implicit return where code execution just "falls off" the end of the function). At that point, the function returns a promise and synchronous execution continues from the point at which the function was called. If it was an exception or a `return` or implicit return (not an `await`), a microtask is queued to settle the promise from the function (rejecting it on exception or fulfilling it on return).

I've highlighted the synchronous parts of that code in yellow:

[image: The code from the question, with highlighting on: 1. async1 and async2's empty parameter lists, the first console.log in each, and (in async1) the call to async2() but not the await on it; 2. The two statements at the end that aren't in any function.]

In your example, when you call `async1` at the bottom, its synchronous portion runs (logging `Async 1` and then calling `async2`, which logs `FROM async 2` during *its* synchronous portion); having run `async2` and gotten a promise from it, `async1` reaches the `await` and returns its own promise; then synchronous execution continues from just after you called it, logging `Synchronous`.

In this particular example, between the `*` and `**` parts, a microtask for the fulfillment of `async2`'s promise is queued. When the task executing the synchronous code in your example is done, that microtask is picked up from the microtask queue and executed — and that settles the promise from `async1` that was waiting for it; `async1`'s code continues, does its log, and then implicitly returns, so a microtask is queued to process that settlement (fulfillment in this case), and picked up from the microtask queue once the `async2` microtask is done executing. But nothing is waiting for that promise, so the settlement doesn't have any apparent effect.

Comment: a microtask is queued within an async function when when that awaited expression or function returns, throws an exception, or the promise resolves correct?

Comment: @TobyHarnish - If I understand your question correctly, then basically yes. :-) The JavaScript engine queues "promise jobs" (microtasks in the HTML spec) to call each of that promise's fulfillment handlers (callbacks) when the promise gets fulfilled; or to call each of its rejection handlers (callbacks) when it gets rejected (one task per callback).[\[1\]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-triggerpromisereactions) It will also queue a promise job (microtask) to call a handler if you add a fulfillment handler to a promise that's already...

Comment: ...fulfilled, or a rejection handler to a promise that's already rejected.[\[2\], steps 10/11](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-performpromisethen) Calling an `async` function creates a promise to report the completion of that function's work. In the function, doing a `return x` (where `x` isn't a promise/[thenable](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-8:~:text=%E2%80%9Cthenable%E2%80%9D%20is%20an%20object%20or%20function%20that%20defines)) fulfills the `async` function's promise (potentially queuing microtasks), and doing a `throw` (or...

Comment: ...allowing a nested `throw` to go uncaught) rejects the promise (potentially queuing microtasks). (Doing `return p` where `p` is a promise *resolves* the `async` function's promise *to* `p`, which may fulfill it, reject it, or leave it pending. Resolving != fulfilling != settling, but people often confuse them; details [on my blog](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).) With `await`, the function's code is on the other side of it, waiting for a callback (in a promise job/microtask) when/if the promise being awaited is settled. Hope that helps!

Comment: (Unrelated to promises, `async` functions -- like any other code -- can also just directly queue a microtask via [`queueMicrotask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask) on browsers, Node.js, and Deno.)

Comment: another question: I am confused over the meaning of microtask. Is it a function or a part of runtime that notifies the event loop to push the callback to the call stack? I have heard this being used in both contexts - some people refer it to a microtask as a function (a callback passed to then or the MutationObserver), while others refers to it as a way of notifying the event loop of more tasks to execute.

Comment: @TobyHarnish - A microtask is a piece of work to be done (in the case of microtasks we queue from code: a function to call), not a notification (that would be *queueing* the microtask, either directly via `queueMicrotask` or indirectly via `await` or `.then`/`.catch`/`.finally` on a promise).